# How to add href in option tag using bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to call id from tab in bootstrap because I want to generate the reports by weekly, monthly, yearly. But I need to choose first in option tag.

This is my code:

```
<select name="generatereport" class="input-small "  >
    <option><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"> weekly </a></option>
    <option><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">monthly </a></option>
    <option><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">yearly </a></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `<option>` elements cannot contain anything other than text.

If you really want a drop down menu of links, then express them as a list (`ul`) and add the drop down functionality with JavaScript.

Comment: hmmm. dropdown is different from <option> . but let me try your suggestion. thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onChange event for < select> element which navigate to tab based on value selected

```
$('.input-small').on('change', function(){
   //get the selected value for example #tab1
   //show the selected tab $('#tab').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Bootstrap dropdown behave like a HTML select like this..

http://bootply.com/109001

Or, you can use one of the "select" plugins for Bootstrap..

http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2